# Omitting measures values related to unknown memeber

Tags: ssas, dimension, ssas-2012, fact

I have a dimension attribute which has either 1 or 0 and few measures which are count, sum or average.
I don't want to display values of measures which are related to attribute 0.
Ex:

- Attribute Name: Is_related
- List item : Values: 0 or 1

  now, there are few measures like count_of_family which has total value of 1000 in which 700 are related to Is_Related 1 and 300 are related to Is_Related to 0.

I have made Is_Related member value (0) disabled but it is not applied on measure. So, for users they are getting 1000 as by default value and when they are selecting 1 it is filtering it down to 700. I want count_of_family measure to display 700 by default (i.e. omitting data related to 0).

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is to make (1) the DefaultMember of the Is_related attribute hierarchy in the dimension.

Using Excel Pivot Tables as an example of what the result is in the front end:

- Whenever the user creates a new Pivot Table, only the sub-cube (Dimension.Is_related.[1],OtherDimension.All,OtherDimension2.All.... etc) is shown
- But if the user drags the Is_related hierarchy onto the pivot table (most appropriately - to the Filters section), only (1) will be selected.  They can then select All (or 0), if they want to.

Downside of non-ALL default members is that you have to remember that you set the default member.  Any MDX query will only query the subcube (excluding Is_related.[0] in your case), unless you specifically include Is_related.ALL in the WHERE.  Which has caught me out in the past, wondering why my results are weird.

Comment: I implemented the same and also made isAgretable to false. Now, when I am browsing it from from cube it is showing me 1 only but when I am browsing it via excel power pivot, I am getting both Unknown and 1.

Comment: I have made Is_Related default to 1. After that, I have created Hierarchy. Is there any way to set default of hierarchy ?

Comment: It needs to be IsAggregatable True, AttributeHierarchyEnabled True.  The latter will automatically create an attribute hierarchy (not visible in design UI) with levels ALL and [leaf].